# How to add hyperlink to file in my file system from specific string in JTextArea component

Tags: swing, hyperlink, jtextarea

I build some GUI in java with Swing, I use JTextArea to display plain text, and i want to take specific string from the content in the JTextArea component and make it hyperlink, so when the user press this hyperlink the match file from the file system is opened.

How can i do it?

Thanks,
Reuth :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) instead.  There is an example of implementing an [HyperlinkListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html) at the top of the JavaDocs.